# Add "Format Document" command to a toolbar, and searching for toolbar commands in general

Tags: visual-studio-2013

On the "HTML Source Editing" toolbar in Visual Studio, there's a "Format Document" button.  I want to add that button to another toolbar because I don't want to have the former toolbar visible.  I can't find the command, though, in any of the command categories.

The command is accessible under the "Edit > Advanced" menu, and it's also shown by going to "Options > Environment > Keyboard" as being associated with the "Edit" category:

[image]

However, it's not in the "Edit" category (or any other that I've looked through) of the "Add Command" dialog:

[image]

I know you can invoke this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, but I'd like to have it on my toolbar as well.

Where is this command?  And is there an easy way to search for toolbar commands?

Comment: In Visual Studio automation model, a keyboard command is not necessarily have a corresponding menu/toolbar item.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov -- noted, but since that menu/toolbar item does exist (as I've pointed out, it's on the "HTML Source Editing" toolbar), I'm wondering where I can find it to add it to another toolbar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command is called **Document Format** and resides in the **Edit** category for placement on a toolbar.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Illogical, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

To add "Format Document" command to a new toolbar (Visual Studio 2022):

1. On the menu bar, select **Tools** --> **Customize**.

   The **Customize** dialog box opens.

2. On the **Toolbars** tab, select the **New** button, specify a name for the toolbar that you want to add, and then select the **OK** button.

   In this case I would recommend "Format Document".

   Now it should look like this:

   [image]

3. Go to the **Commands** tab (1). Select **Toolbar** (2) and choose the **Format Document** (3), created in step 2:

   [image]

4. Click on **Add Command...** (1), then choose **Edit** (2) and **Document Format** (3). Then click OK (4):

   [image]

5. Now it should look like this. Click on **Close**:

   [image]

6. The result is a newly created toolbar with the **Format Document** command:

   [image]

Comment: Works well with VS2019